# Regular Expression Word Boundary and Special Characters

Tags: regex

I have a regular expression to escape all special characters in a search string.  This works great, however I can't seem to get it to work with word boundaries.  For example, with the haystack

```
add +
```

or

```
add (+)
```

and the needle

```
+
```

the regular expression `/\+/gi` matches the "+".  However the regular expression `/\b\+/gi` doesn't.  Any ideas on how to make this work?

Using

```
add (plus)
```

as the haystack and `/\bplus/gi` as the regex, it matches fine.  I just can't figure out why the escaped characters are having problems.

Comment: I changed the formatting of your sample strings to make the spaces in them more obvious; they're essential to understanding why your regex is failing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`\b` is a *zero-width assertion*: it doesn't consume any characters, it just asserts that a certain condition holds at a given position.  A word boundary asserts that the position is either preceded by a word character and not followed by one, or followed by a word character and not preceded by one. (A "word character" is a letter, a digit, or an underscore.)  In your string:

```
add +
```

...there's a word boundary at the beginning because the `a` is not preceded by a word character, and there's one after the second `d` because it's not followed by a word character.  The `\b` in your regex (`/\b\+/`) is trying to match between the space and the `+`, which doesn't work because neither of those is a word character.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense actually. I take it then that there's no  way to achieve what I want to without creating a list of pre-defined characters (such as `\s`, `\(`, `\[`, etc.) to match against before the `+`?

Comment: Do you want to match anything that's *not* a word character?  That would be `\W` (capital 'w').  Or you can use `\B` to assert that the `+` is not preceded by a word character.

Comment: Definitely not *not* a word character, but your explanation of the actual usage of `\b` gave me a kick in the right direction. I'm now doing a JS check on the first character of my regex. If it's a `\\` I don't append the `\b`. If it isn't, I do. Seem to be getting the results I wanted. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing it to:

```
/\b\s?+/gi
```

Edit:

Extend this concept as far as you want. If you want the first + after any word boundary:

```
/\b[^+]*+/gi
```

Comment: That works in the specific example I gave, but doesn't account for word boundaries properly.  For example, it doesn't work on 'add (+)' as the haystack.

Comment: I edited my answer to account for a more general case, but if that's not what you're looking for, then you need to be more specific on what you want.

Comment: Not sure how to be more specific.  I need to use the word boundary \b to specify that the special character is at the beginning of a word.  I updated the question to include 'add (+)' as an example, but there are obviously dozens more where some character (other than whitespace) designates a word boundary.

Comment: Then I'm sorry, but I can't help you figure out what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Boundaries are very conditional assertions; what they anchor depends on what they touch. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4213800/is-there-something-like-a-counter-variable-in-regular-expression-replace/4214173#4214173) for a detailed explanation, along with what else you can do to deal with it.