# Match a whole word in a string using dynamic regex

Tags: python, regex

I am looking to see whether a word occurs in a sentence using regex. Words are separated by spaces, but may have punctuation on either side. If the word is in the middle of the string, the following match works (it prevents part-words from matching, allows punctuation on either side of the word).

```
match_middle_words = " [^a-zA-Z\d ]{0,}" + word + "[^a-zA-Z\d ]{0,} "
```

This won't however match the first or last word, since there is no trailing/leading space. So, for these cases, I have also been using:

```
match_starting_word = "^[^a-zA-Z\d]{0,}" + word + "[^a-zA-Z\d ]{0,} "
match_end_word = " [^a-zA-Z\d ]{0,}" + word + "[^a-zA-Z\d]{0,}$"
```

and then combining with

```
 match_string = match_middle_words  + "|" + match_starting_word  +"|" + match_end_word
```

Is there a simple way to avoid the need of three match terms. Specifically, is there a way of specifying 'ether a space or the start of file (i.e. "^") and similar, 'either a space or the end of the file (i.e. "$")?

Comment: Can ya give some examples?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Why not use a *word boundary*?

```
match_string = r'\b' + word + r'\b'
match_string = r'\b{}\b'.format(word)
match_string = rf'\b{word}\b'          # Python 3.7+ required
```

If you have a list of words (say, in a `words` variable) to be matched as a whole word, use

```
match_string = r'\b(?:{})\b'.format('|'.join(words))
match_string = rf'\b(?:{"|".join(words)})\b'         # Python 3.7+ required
```

In this case, you will make sure the word is only captured when it is surrounded by non-word characters. Also note that `\b` matches at the string start and end. So, no use adding 3 alternatives.

[Sample code](http://ideone.com/Qa39wj):

```
import re
strn = "word hereword word, there word"
search = "word"
print re.findall(r"\b" + search + r"\b", strn)
```

And we found our 3 matches:

```
['word', 'word', 'word']
```

***NOTE ON "WORD" BOUNDARIES***

When the "words" are in fact chunks of any chars you should `re.escape` them before passing to the regex pattern:

```
match_string = r'\b{}\b'.format(re.escape(word)) # a single escaped "word" string passed
match_string = r'\b(?:{})\b'.format("|".join(map(re.escape, words))) # words list is escaped
match_string = rf'\b(?:{"|".join(map(re.escape, words))})\b' # Same as above for Python 3.7+
```

If the words to be matched as whole words may start/end with special characters, `\b` [won't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3241692/regular-expression-word-boundary-and-special-characters), use *unambiguous word boundaries*:

```
match_string = r'(?<!\w){}(?!\w)'.format(re.escape(word))
match_string = r'(?<!\w)(?:{})(?!\w)'.format("|".join(map(re.escape, words)))
```

If the word boundaries are whitespace chars or start/end of string, use *whitespace boundaries*, `(?<!\S)...(?!\S)`:

```
match_string = r'(?<!\S){}(?!\S)'.format(word)
match_string = r'(?<!\S)(?:{})(?!\S)'.format("|".join(map(re.escape, words)))
```

Comment: Thank you - that that was far far simpler solution than I anticipated!

Comment: FYI: In case the number of words to search for is more than a hundred, thousands, it makes sense to build a regex trie, e.g. as is described in [*Speed up millions of regex replacements in Python 3*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42789508/3832970).