# Python count string (word) in column of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

i have the following dataframe (df_hvl) with the columnname "FzListe" and the following data:

```
FzListe
7MA1, 7OS1
7MA1, 7ZJB
7MA2, 7MA3, 7OS1
76G1, 7MA1, 7OS1
7MA1, 7OS1
71E5, 71E6, 7MA1, FSS1
71E4, 7MA1, 7MB1, 7OS1
71E6, 7MA1, 7OS1
7MA1
7MA1, 7MB1, 7OS1
7MA1
7MA1, 7MA2, 7OS1
04, 7MA1
76G1, 7MA1, 7OS1
76G1, 7MA1, 7OS1
7MA1, 7OS1
7MA1
76G1, 7MA1, 7OS1
76G1, 7MA1, 7OS1
71E6, 7MA1
7MA1, 7MA2, 7OS1
7MA1
7MA1
7MA1
7MA1, 7OS1
76G1, 7MA1
```

I want to search for the string "7MA" only and count how often it appears in the list. (The list is originally much longer than that snippet). I want not to search only for 7MA1 because its possible that in one line it appears also with 7MA2 and/or 7MA3 and so on...

The Dataframe is called df_hvl and i searched for a solution but didnt find one.

Comment: What is desired output?

Comment: a counting how often 7MA appears in the column (including 7MA1, 7MA2, 7MA3 and so on)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you need [`str.count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.count.html) with `sum`:

```
print (df_hvl.FzListe.str.count(substr))
0     1
1     1
2     2
3     1
4     1
5     1
6     1
7     1
8     1
9     1
10    1
11    2
12    1
13    1
14    1
15    1
16    1
17    1
18    1
19    1
20    2
21    1
22    1
23    1
24    1
25    1
Name: FzListe, dtype: int64

substr = '7MA'
print (df_hvl.FzListe.str.count(substr).sum())
29
```

Comment: nice it is really elegant

Answer (score 2):

this will work too probably

```
df_hvl.FzListe.map(lambda d: "7MA" in d).sum()
```

Comment: This worked for me, and also seems to work with a series column (strings inside brackets) which is cool.

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this I think

```
b=0
for index in df.index:
    A=df.loc[row,'FzList'].split(',')
    for element in A:
        if '7MA'in element: 
            b+=1
return b
```

Answer (score -2):

You need to use [`Series.str.count`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.count.html) that accepts a *regex* pattern as the first argument, and an optional second argument accepting [regex *flags*](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#compilation-flags) that can modify the matching behavior:

```py
import re
df_hvl['FzListe'].str.count(re.escape(substr))
## enabling case insensitive match:
df_hvl['FzListe'].str.count(re.escape(substr), re.I)
```

You need to use [`re.escape`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.escape) as `Series.str.count` will fail if a `substr` contains special regex metacharacters.

*Related posts*:

- Escaping strings for use in regex: [Escaping regex string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/280435/3832970)

In case you need to match a whole word...

- Adaptive dynamic word boundaries: [Word boundary with words starting or ending with special characters gives unexpected results](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45145626/3832970)
- Dynamic word boundaries: [Match a whole word in a string using dynamic regex](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29996079/3832970)
- Handling thousands of words to search for as whole words: [Performance of using regex matched groups in pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68153947/3832970)