# Performance of using regex matched groups in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, regex, pandas, performance

I have a pandas series of ~350k rows, and I want to apply the [pandas.Series.str.extract](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html?pandas.Series.str.extract) function using a regular expression consisting of ~100 substrings, such as:

`'(item0|item1|item2|item3|item4|item5|item6|item7|item8|item9|item10|item11|item12|item13|item14|item15|item16|item17|item18|item19|item20|item21|item22|item23|item24|item25|item26|item27|item28|item29|item30|item31|item32|item33|item34|item35|item36|item37|item38|item39|item40|item41|item42|item43|item44|item45|item46|item47|item48|item49|item50|item51|item52|item53|item54|item55|item56|item57|item58|item59|item60|item61|item62|item63|item64|item65|item66|item67|item68|item69|item70|item71|item72|item73|item74|item75|item76|item77|item78|item79|item80|item81|item82|item83|item84|item85|item86|item87|item88|item89|item90|item91|item92|item93|item94|item95|item96|item97|item98|item99|item100)'`

The extract is too slow: it takes 1 minute in my jupyter notebook (Python 3.9). Why is it so slow and how to speed it up?

**Edit 1** I used 'itemX' as an example, but it can be substituted by any substring. The regular expression could be something like

```
'(carrageenan|dihydro|basketball|etc...)'
```

**Edit 2** Answer to some comments:

- I'm looking for exact matches
- I already precompile the regex using `re.compile()`

Comment: Why not use pattern `r'(item\d+)'` ?

Comment: I used 'itemX' as an example, but it can be any substring. The regular expression could be something like '(carrageenan|dihydro|basketball|etc...)

Comment: Does pre-compiling the regex pattern with `re.compile()` help ?

Comment: @SeaBean [pandas does that](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/7c48ff4409c622c582c56a5702373f726de08e96/pandas/core/strings/accessor.py#L3041).

Comment: Can you provide a minimal working example? I am not able to reproduce your problem with random strings (of size 6-10) with one pd.Series of 350k items and your provided regexp. It takes between 0.1 to 0.3s on my machine (so about 300x times faster...).

Comment: @MustafaAydın  Thanks for the info.  The doc is about `str.extract()` and related.  Is that all Pandas methods allowing regex do the same ?  How about `str.contains()` ?

Comment: `str.contains` [does too](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/7c48ff4409c622c582c56a5702373f726de08e96/pandas/core/strings/object_array.py#L110). If we check others, they also probably do. @SeaBean

Comment: That's really nice!  Much appreciated @MustafaAydın

Answer (score 5):

In most cases, the problem with searching for multiple words is related to the fact that many of the search words share the same prefix, and the more such words are in the list, the more backtracking steps are required to find a match, which slows the code execution.

A [regex trie](https://github.com/ermanh/trieregex) will come to rescue here, together with [word boundaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324676/what-is-a-word-boundary-in-regex-does-b-match-hyphen) (since you need an exact match). Install `pip install trieregex` and use

```py
from trieregex import TrieRegEx
keywords = ['item0','item1','item2','item3']
tr = TrieRegEx(*keywords)
pattern = fr'\b({tr.regex()})\b'
```

Then, you can use the `pattern` with `.str.extract()` method.

If you do not need to use some third party library to generate the regex trie, you can use the [code from this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42789508/3832970).

Comment: Interesting, but isn't that the purpose of regexp compilation/engine to do such a work? I know that some engine generate a minimal deterministic automaton like RE and generally not the standard PCRE engine, but this simplification seems a basic one for a regexp engine...

Comment: @JérômeRichard The `re` regex engine does not do this under the hood.