# Match if keyword inside a string starts/ends or both with non-alphanumeric words

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

My requirement in simple plain English

Match if keyword inside a string starts/ends or both with non-alphanumeric words, or exact match

**Keyword:** china

```
'CHINA', #match
'CHINA ROM' #match
'CHINA WAREHOUSE', #match
'CHINA-WAREHOUSE', #match
'CHINA-ROM', #match
'dsa china', #match
'CHINALOCAL', #No
'CHINAOO' #No
```

As per my current knowledge of Regexes, I can do something like

```
keyword = keyword.lower()
if keyword == '' string \ 
    or re.match(r"china[^a-zA-Z0-9]", keyword, flags=re.IGNORECASE) \
    or re.match(r"[^a-zA-Z0-9]china", keyword, flags=re.IGNORECASE) \
    or re.match(r"[^a-zA-Z0-9]china[^a-zA-Z0-9]", keyword, flags=re.IGNORECASE):
    print("matched")
```

Is there any single regex expression that can perform all checks I want?

Comment: Do you mean words that do not contain a digit? Only `[a-zA-Z]`?

Comment: maybe it's duplicaated :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29996079/match-a-whole-word-in-a-string-using-dynamic-regex

Comment: `if re.search(r'\bchina\b', s, re.I)`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it does not match `dsa china`

Comment: [It matches well](https://ideone.com/vVpK1s).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew is it possible you can  write an answer with few details

Comment: [I have written it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29996092/3832970), no need to duplicate SO content.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew then I should delete my question, but I cannot because SO doesnt allow me to delete since it has answers

Comment: You do not have to.

Answer (score 1):

For your example data, you might use

```
^(?:[A-Za-z]+ )*china(?:[ -][A-Za-z]+)*$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:[A-Za-z]+ )*` Repeat 0+ times matching 1+ times A-Za-z followed by a space
- `china` Match literally
- `?:[ -][A-Za-z]+)*` Repeat 0+ times matching a space or `-`, then 1+ times A-Za-z
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yc84Mo/1)

Answer (score 1):

```
data = [
"'CHINA'",
"'CHINA ROM'",
"'CHINA WAREHOUSE'",
"'CHINA-WAREHOUSE'",
"'CHINA-ROM'",
"'dsa china'",
"'CHINALOCAL'",
"'CHINAOO'",
]

import re

for d in data:
    if re.findall(r'[^a-z]china[^a-z]', d, flags=re.I):
        print('{: <20} match!'.format(d))
    else:
        print('{: <20} not match!'.format(d))
```

Prints:

```
'CHINA'              match!
'CHINA ROM'          match!
'CHINA WAREHOUSE'    match!
'CHINA-WAREHOUSE'    match!
'CHINA-ROM'          match!
'dsa china'          match!
'CHINALOCAL'         not match!
'CHINAOO'            not match!
```

EDIT: As Wiktor said in the comments `re.findall(r'\bchina\b', d, flags=re.I)` might be what you want!

Comment: ah, nice trick to enclose words in single quotes :P