# How to extract exact matches with list from a dataframe column?

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

I have a large dataframe with text that I want to use to find matches from a list of words (around 1k words in there).

I have managed to get the absence/presence of the word from the list in the dataframe, but it is also important to me to know which word matched. Sometimes there is exact match with more than one word from the list, I would like to have them all.

I tried to use the code below, but it gives me partial matches - syllables instead of full words.

```
#this is a code to recreate the initial DF

import pandas as pd

df_data= [['orange','0'],
['apple and lemon','1'],
['lemon and orange','1']]

df= pd.DataFrame(df_data,columns=['text','match','exact word'])
```

Initial DF:

```
 text                 match
 orange               0
 apple and lemon      1
 lemon and orange     1
```

This is the list of words I need to match

```
 exactmatch = ['apple', 'lemon']
```

Expected result:

```
 text                    match  exact words
 orange                    0         0 
 apple and lemon           1        'apple','lemon'
 lemon and orange          1        'lemon'
```

This is what I've tried:

```
# for some rows it gives me words I want, 
#and for some it gives me parts of the word

#regex attempt 1, gives me partial matches (syllables or single letters)

pattern1 = '|'.join(exactmatch)
df['contains'] = df['text'].str.extract("(" + "|".join(exactmatch) 
+")", expand=False)

#regex attempt 2 - this gives me an error - unexpected EOL

df['contains'] = df['text'].str.extractall
("(" + "|".join(exactmatch) +")").unstack().apply(','.join, 1)

#TypeError: ('sequence item 1: expected str instance, float found', 
#'occurred at index 2')

#no regex attempt, does not give me matches if the word is in there

lst = list(df['text'])
match = []
for w in lst:
 if w in exactmatch:
    match.append(w)
    break
```

Comment: Can you post your expected ouput?

Comment: @harvpan The expected output is in the df - column 'exact words'. Will edit the question now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `str.findall`

**Ex:**

```
exactmatch = ['apple', 'lemon']
df_data= [['orange'],['apple and lemon',],['lemon and orange'],]

df= pd.DataFrame(df_data,columns=['text'])
df['exact word'] = df["text"].str.findall(r"|".join(exactmatch)).apply(", ".join)
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
               text    exact word
0            orange              
1   apple and lemon  apple, lemon
2  lemon and orange         lemon
```

Comment: Thanks! It works, but in addition to giving me full matches it also gives me syllable matches in a bigger dataset. E.g.:  one of the matches looks like this "a, la, et, identify, la, are, la, ideology, ...". I need the words 'identify' and 'ideology' because they are in my list, but I'm not sure how to eliminate the partial matches (letter combinations).

Comment: Looks like you need regex boundaries \b

Comment: thanks :) Could you please help me and show where I should put them?

Comment: ex `str.findall(r"\b"+"|".join(exactmatch) + r"\b")`

Comment: @Rakesh seems like the regex boundaries still gave the same result like what alinaz mentioned

Answer (score 0):

The problem of matching some word(s) as "exact" words or match is not a simple regex task. The final solution depends on your concrete use case, what you mean by "exact" in each specific scenario.

You need to build a pattern dynamically from the list of words using one of the ways described in [Match a whole word in a string using dynamic regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29996092/3832970) or [Word boundary with words starting or ending with special characters gives unexpected results](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45145800/3832970).

Then, you can simply use `Series.str.findall` without worrying about whether your pattern contains a capturing group or not:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'text':['orange','apple and lemon', 'lemon and orange'], 'match':['0','1','1']})
exactmatch = ['apple', 'lemon']
pattern = fr'\b({"|".join(exactmatch)})\b' # This works for words consisting of letters, digits or underscores
df['exact word'] = df['text'].str.findall(pattern).str.join(", ")
# => >>> df
# =>                text match    exact word
# => 0            orange     0              
# => 1   apple and lemon     1  apple, lemon
# => 2  lemon and orange     1         lemon
```

If you need to rely on *exact* match but not `\b` word boundaries:

- Full string match: `fr'^({"|".join([re.escape(word) for word in exactmatch])})\Z'` (this is the weirdest case for `.findall`, `Series.str.extract` makes more sense, and even non-regex approaches must be considered here, like `.isin`)
- **Word boundaries with longest match support when words can contain special chars *inside* words and overlapping terms** (extract `sour lemon` from `I have a sour lemon` when the words are `['sour', 'lemon', 'sour lemon']`): `pattern = fr'\b({"|".join([re.escape(word) for word in sorted(exactmatch, key=len, reverse=False)])})\b'`
- **Whitespace boundaries** (match occurs between whitespaces or whitespaces and start/end of string: `pattern = fr'(?<!\S)({"|".join([re.escape(word) for word in sorted(exactmatch, key=len, reverse=False)])})(?!\S)'`
- **Unambiguous word boundaries** (no match in between word - letter, digit, underscore - chars: `pattern = fr'(?<!\w)({"|".join([re.escape(word) for word in sorted(exactmatch, key=len, reverse=False)])})(?!\w)'`
- **Unambiguous word boundaries with underscores subtracted** (no match in between letters or digits, but `_lemon_` is a case of an exact `lemon` word): `pattern = fr'(?<![^\W_])({"|".join([re.escape(word) for word in sorted(exactmatch, key=len, reverse=False)])})(?![^\W_])'`
- **Letter boundaries** (no match in between letters, but `_lemon_` and `0lemon1` are cases of an exact `lemon` word): `pattern = fr'(?<![^\W\d_])({"|".join([re.escape(word) for word in sorted(exactmatch, key=len, reverse=False)])})(?![^\W\d_])'`
- Adaptive dynamic word boundaries *Type 1* (when you have no control over the words to match, and they can contain special chars anywhere, no special context restriction for intial and trailing special chars): `pattern = fr'(?:(?!\w)|\b(?=\w))({"|".join([re.escape(word) for word in sorted(exactmatch, key=len, reverse=False)])})(?:(?<=\w)\b|(?<!\w))'`
- Adaptive dynamic word boundaries *Type 2* (when you have no control over the words to match, and they can contain special chars anywhere, and if there are special chars at the start or end of the word, no other word char can appear right next to it): `pattern = fr'(?:\B(?!\w)|\b(?=\w))({"|".join([re.escape(word) for word in sorted(exactmatch, key=len, reverse=False)])})(?:(?<=\w)\b|(?<!\w)\B)'`.