# Python replace function not replacing all words

Tags: python, regex, string, replace

I have a list of words/phrases that I want to filter out of a string. However, my code doesn't filter out all the words. Why is this happening?

```py
stop_words = ['nbsp']
string = 'applicant nbsp entrepreneur nbsp develop level nbsp export artist nbsp export entrepreneur nbsp record label nbsp nbsp music publisher nbsp nbsp music manager'

for word in stop_words:
    if word in string:
        string = re.sub(" {} ".format(word), " ", string)
print(string)
```

After running this code, this was the output.

```py
'applicant entrepreneur develop level export artist export entrepreneur record label nbsp music publisher nbsp music manager'
```

As you can see, 'nbsp' is still in the string. 
Additionally, in my actual list of stop words, I have elements in the list that are more than one word long. For example, "sleeping in" is an element. I also did not omit the spaces on either side of word so that single-letter cases such as "a" would not be filtered out of words with "a" in them.

Comment: Because there are single spaces between words, so your regex can't match consecutive matches as the last `" "`consumes a space after a word making it unavailable for the next match.

Comment: Also, `for word in stop_words:` will take too long, build a dynamic pattern matching the whole word using one of the approaches described in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29996092/3832970). Looks like you need whitespace boundaries.

Comment: As per [my post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29996092/3832970), `string = re.sub(r'(?<!\S)(?:{})(?!\S)'.format("|".join(map(re.escape, stop_words))), '', string)`