# Dynamic regex in dataframe

Tags: python, regex, pandas

Having a dataframe as follows:

```
df= pd.DataFrame({'category':['Fishing','Refrigeration','store'],'synonyms_text':['seafood','foodlocker',' food']})
```

And a list as follows:

```
list_desc=['FOOD', 'GROWERS', 'INTERNATIONAL']
```

How can I iterate over the `list_desc` to create a dynamic regular expression to be used in the dataframe?

```
for word in list_desc:
    print(word.lower())
    df_tmp= df.loc[df['synonyms_text'].str.contains(r'\bfood\b')]
```

Where `food` has to be substituted by `word` variable.

Thanks

Comment: There are lots of options, and watch out for caveats. See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29996092/3832970).

Answer (score 0):

You can just construct your regex dynamically using `format()` like in `r'\b{0}\b'.format(word)`

Example:

```py
for word in list_desc:
    df_tmp= df.loc[df['synonyms_text'].str.contains(r'\b{0}\b'.format(re.escape(word.lower())))]
```

More info: [How to use a variable inside a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6930982/how-to-use-a-variable-inside-a-regular-expression)

Comment: Perfect, it worked. Thanks

Comment: @JuanPerez, glad that it's solved. And if my answer is helpful, could you please help accept it? Thanks :)

Comment: It won't work once the `word` contains special chars. Word boundaries will stop working once the special char appears at the start/end of the word.

Comment: better to use `f-string` for stringformatting

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, will add re.escape to the solution.