# Pandas: Grouping rows by list in CSV file?

Tags: regex, python-3.x, pandas

In an effort to make our budgeting life a bit easier and help myself learn; I am creating a small program in python that takes data from our exported bank csv.

I will give you an example of what I want to do with this data. Say I want to group all of my fast food expenses together. There are many different names with different totals in the description column but I want to see it all tabulated as one "Fast Food " expense.

For instance the Csv is setup like this:

```
Date             Description           Debit    Credit
1/20/20      POS PIN BLAH BLAH ###     1.75      NaN
```

I figured out how to group them with an or statement:

```
contains = df.loc[df['Description'].str.contains('food court|whataburger', flags = re.I, regex = True)]
```

I ultimately would like to have it read off of a list? I would like to group all my expenses into categories and check those category variable names so that it would only output from that list.

I tried something like:

```
fast_food = ['Macdonald', 'Whataburger', 'pizza hut']
```

That obviously didn't work.

If there is a better way of doing this I am wide open to suggestions.

Also I have looked through quite a few posts here on stack and have yet to find the answer (although I am sure I overlooked it)

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am still learning.

Thanks

Comment: Are you saying you want to group the list of `fast_food` and search it by `str.contains`?

Comment: you can create a map from all the fast food places but there is no automatic way to do this (bar using NLP) or having a list of every place you eat or could eat in a list to filter it by beore a groupby

Comment: Right. I also want it to look at that row's debit category and give me the sum of all in that list. I can't seem to get str.contains to work alongside a list to do that though.

Comment: `...str.contains('|'.join(fast_food), flags = re.I, regex = True)`?

Comment: @HenryYik that worked, is there a way to make them show me their individual sums once grouped? When I just add .sum() to the end it works but it doesn't show me all the data. It is a bit jumbled up. For instance (All macdonalds = 30.00)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign a new column using `str.extract` and then `groupby`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"description":['Macdonald something', 'Whataburger something', 'pizza hut something',
                                  'Whataburger something','Macdonald something','Macdonald otherthing',],
                   "debit":[1.75,2.0,3.5,4.5,1.5,2.0]})

fast_food = ['Macdonald', 'Whataburger', 'pizza hut']

df["found"] = df["description"].str.extract(f'({"|".join(fast_food)})',flags=re.I)

print (df.groupby("found").sum())

#
             debit
found             
Macdonald     5.25
Whataburger   6.50
pizza hut     3.50
```

Comment: I guess I was not clear enough. I apologize. I want the sum of their corresponding categories "Debit" or "Credit" that is on the same row, not the number of times Macdonalds show up.

Comment: Thank you @HenryYik

Answer (score 0):

Use dynamic pattern building:

```
fast_food = ['Macdonald', 'Whataburger', 'pizza hut']
pattern = r"\b(?:{})\b".format("|".join(map(re.escape, fast_food)))    
contains = df.loc[df['Description'].str.contains(pattern, flags = re.I, regex = True)]
```

The `\b` word boundaries find whole words, not partial words.

The `re.escape` will protect special characters and they will be parsed as literal characters.

If `\b` does not work for you, check other approaches at [Match a whole word in a string using dynamic regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29996079/match-a-whole-word-in-a-string-using-dynamic-regex)