# Python find offsets of a word token in a text

Tags: python, tokenize, stringtokenizer

I wrote this function `findTokenOffset` that finds the offset of a given word in a pre-tokenized text (as a list of spaced words or according to a certain tokenizer).

import re, json

```
def word_regex_ascii(word):
    return r"\b{}\b".format(re.escape(word))

def findTokenOffset(text,tokens):
  seen = {} # map if a token has been see already!
  items=[] # word tokens
  my_regex = word_regex_ascii
  # for each token word
  for index_word,word in enumerate(tokens):

      r = re.compile(my_regex(word), flags=re.I | re.X | re.UNICODE)

      item = {}
      # for each matched token in sentence
      for m in r.finditer(text):

          token=m.group()
          characterOffsetBegin=m.start()
          characterOffsetEnd=characterOffsetBegin+len(m.group()) - 1 # LP: star from 0
          
          found=-1
          if word in seen:
              found=seen[word]
          
          if characterOffsetBegin > found:
              # store last word has been seen
              seen[word] = characterOffsetEnd
              item['index']=index_word+1 #// word index starts from 1
              item['word']=token
              item['characterOffsetBegin'] = characterOffsetBegin
              item['characterOffsetEnd'] = characterOffsetEnd
              items.append(item)

              break
  return items
```

This code works ok when the tokens are single words like

```
text = "George Washington came to Washington"
tokens = text.split()
offsets = findTokenOffset(text,tokens)
print(json.dumps(offsets, indent=2))
```

But, supposed to have tokens having a multi-token fashion like here:

```
text = "George Washington came to Washington"
tokens = ["George Washington", "Washington"]
offsets = findTokenOffset(text,tokens)
print(json.dumps(offsets, indent=2))
```

the offset does not work properly, due to repeating words in different tokens:

```
[
  {
    "index": 1,
    "word": "George Washington",
    "characterOffsetBegin": 0,
    "characterOffsetEnd": 16
  },
  {
    "index": 2,
    "word": "Washington",
    "characterOffsetBegin": 7,
    "characterOffsetEnd": 16
  }
]
```

How to add support to *multi-token* and *overlapped token regex* matching (thanks to the suggestion in comments for this exact problem's name)?

Comment: What is your expected output? is this related to overlapped regex matching?

Comment: Do that with a single pass. How large is your vocabulary (number of `tokens`)?

Comment: Hey @Aaron yes it's a "token overlapping" regex matching, correct.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Hi Wiktor, I do not have a specific number, let's say it's a whole document, like a wikipedia page, so it could be huge or not. I's interesting your single pass approach. I was thinking to this, like a sort of vectorial algorithm, but did not figured out how.

Comment: This approach may become very messy if you need to have the token indices in the resulting JSON, see https://ideone.com/jMEtRb. It looks fine but you just have no pretty way to get the information on what token matched.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks. This approach works ok in most of cases, but it fails when having like `text = "George Washington came to Washington Washington.com"` and 
`tokens = ["George Washington", "Washington", "Washington.com"]` this will result in matching `Washington` within `Washington.com`

Comment: I do not see what fails [here](https://ideone.com/6HHFga).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew wops, sorry that works, I meant this sequence: `tokens = ["George Washington", "Washington"]`. In this case the second token will match twice: the whole word and the token within `Washington.com`.

Comment: @loretoparisi But what is the token boundary then? I thought it was a word boundary.

Comment: ah so. It should not match the word `Washington` when in `Washington.com`, so it should respect the boundary, yes, to match only when it's alone like `\b$1\b`

Comment: What is the token boundary? `Washington` in `Washington.com` is a whole word as there is a word boundary between `n` and `.`. It is a valid match given the requirements. If you want to fail the match if there is a `.` right after a word and there is a word char on the right, you can use `re.compile(fr'(?<!\w)(?:{"|".join(sorted(map(re.escape, tokens), key=len, reverse=True))})\b(?!\.\b)', re.I )`, see [demo](https://ideone.com/A74a9M).

Comment: Please let know if that is something worth posting, I will post as an answer with explanations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not need the search phrase/word index information in the resulting output, you can use the following approach:

```py
import re,json
 
def findTokenOffset(text, pattern):
    items = []
    for m in pattern.finditer(text):
        item = {}
        item['word']=m.group()
        item['characterOffsetBegin'] = m.start()
        item['characterOffsetEnd'] = m.end()
        items.append(item)
    return items
 
text = "George Washington came to Washington Washington.com"
tokens = ["George Washington", "Washington"]
pattern = re.compile(fr'(?<!\w)(?:{"|".join(sorted(map(re.escape, tokens), key=len, reverse=True))})(?!\w)(?!\.\b)', re.I )
offsets = findTokenOffset(text,pattern)
print(json.dumps(offsets, indent=2))
```

The output of the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/7Tmg1B):

```py
[
  {
    "word": "George Washington",
    "characterOffsetBegin": 0,
    "characterOffsetEnd": 17
  },
  {
    "word": "Washington",
    "characterOffsetBegin": 26,
    "characterOffsetEnd": 36
  }
]
```

The main part is `pattern = re.compile(fr'(?<!\w)(?:{"|".join(sorted(map(re.escape, tokens), key=len, reverse=True))})\b(?!\.\b)', re.I )` that does the following:

- `map(re.escape, tokens)` - escapes special chars inside `tokens` strings
- `sorted(..., key=len, reverse=True)` - sorts the items in escaped `tokens` by length in a descending order (so that `Washigton Post` could match earlier than `Washington`)
- `"|".join(...)` - created an alternation list of `tokens`, `token1|token2|etc`
- `(?<!\w)(?:...)(?!\w)(?!\.\b)` - is the final pattern that matches all the alternatives in `tokens` as whole words. `(?<!\w)` and `(?!\w)` are used to enable word boundary detection even if the `tokens` start/end with a special character.

**NOTE ON WORD BOUNDARIES**

You should check your *token boundary* requirements. I added `(?!\.\b)` as you mention that `Washington` should not match in `Washington.com`, so I inferred to want to fail any word match when it is immediately followed with `.` and a word boundary. There are a lot of other possible solutions, the main one being *whitespace boundaries*, `(?<!\S)` and `(?!\S)`.

Besides, see [Match a whole word in a string using dynamic regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29996092/3832970).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to lookup for Washington, but not George Washington, you can remove the sentences you found from initial string. So, you can sort the 'tokens' by the word quantity. That gives you an opportunity to firstly scan the senteces, and after that, the words.

Comment: I think you are suggesting to use a placeholder at each matching step, right?