# Regex match two strings with given number of words in between strings

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds

I want to match characters including and between two strings. (for a given number of words acceptable between them)

For example:

`text = 'I want apples and oranges'`
Parameters are `'apples'`, `'oranges'` and `k=2`, which is the max allowable words in between these strings words. I am expecting the output to be `'apples and oranges'` because there is only one word between the two given strings

This is very similar to the `(?<=...)` pattern in regex but I am unable to define the number of acceptable words in between and I want the relevant text extracted instead of just what's in between

What I have now:

```
import re
text = 'I want apples and oranges'
pattern = "(?<=apples)(.*)(?=oranges)"
m = re.search(pattern, text)
print(m)
```

> > <re.Match object; span=(13, 18), match=' and '>

This outputs `' and '`. But I want to get the output of `apples and oranges`, instead of only whats in between. And I want to be able to limit the number of acceptable words between apples and oranges. For example, if I define `k = 2` and if the sentence is "I want apples along with some oranges" this should not match because there are 3 words between apples and oranges.

Does anyone know if I can do this with regex as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like

```py
import re
text = 'I want apples and oranges'
k = 2
pattern = f"apples(?:\s+\w+){{0,{k}}}\s+oranges"
m = re.search(pattern, text)
if m:
    print(m.group())

# => apples and oranges
```

Here, I used `\w+` to match a word. If the word is a non-whitespace chunk, you need to use

```py
pattern = f"apples(?:\s+\S+){{0,{k}}}\s+oranges"
```

See [this Python demo](https://ideone.com/KEB3qg).

If you need to add word boundaries, you need to study the [Word boundary with words starting or ending with special characters gives unexpected results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45145626) and [Match a whole word in a string using dynamic regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29996079) posts. For the current example, `fr"\bapples(?:\s+\w+){{0,{k}}}\s+oranges\b"` will work.

The pattern will look like `apples(?:\s+\w+){0,k}\s+oranges` and match

- `apples` - an `apples` string
- `(?:\s+\w+){0,k}` - zero to *k* repetitions of one or more whitespaces and one or more word chars
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
- `oranges` an `oranges` string.