# Passing variable to Regex extact pandas

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I am trying to use to do a regex extract with Pandas by using the value from another column as a variable.

`df = pd.DataFrame({'text': ["The final is one of the most famous snooker matches of all time and pa", "Davis trailed for the first time at the event in the quarter-finals, as he played Terry Griffiths. "],'key': ["snooker", 'quarter-finals']})`

I was thinking of building a string as a parameter and passing it to the function like so

`reg = '((?:\S+\s+){0,10}\b'+'snooker'+'\b\s*(?:\S+\b\s*){0,10})'`
`df['text'].str.extract(r'reg')`

but it generates this error

ValueError: pattern contains no capture groups

which I am assuming is due to the syntax of  `"(r'reg')"`

Comment: There are a couple of issues here: 1) word boundaries are set with literal `\b`, not with a backspace char, 2) you cannot place variables into a string literal which is not an f-string like that, but 3) what do you need to do?

Comment: nop I need the "r" in the parameter ```(r'something')```

Comment: Try just `df['text'].str.extract(fr'((?:\S+\s+){{0,10}}\b{keyword_var}\b(?:\s+\S+){{0,10}})')` where `keyword_var` is your alphanumeric word variable.

Comment: yes that works Wiktor Stribiżew thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of issues here:

- Word boundaries are set with literal `\b` (r"\b"), not with a backspace char (`"\b"`),
- You cannot place variables into a regular, normal string literal, you need to use `format()` or f-strings
- You *also need a capturing group* in the pattern.

You can use

```py
df['result'] = df['text'].str.extract(fr'((?:\S+\s+){{0,10}}\b{keyword_var}\b(?:\s+\S+){{0,10}})')
```

Note:

- `fr'...'` - define a raw f-string literal with variable interpolation support and parsing backslashes as literal chars
- `((?:\S+\s+){{0,10}}\b{keyword_var}\b(?:\s+\S+){{0,10}})` - a pattern with a single capturing group wrapping the whole pattern, this group value will be the return value.
- If your `keyword` is not a purely alphanumeric string, you will need to reconsider [using word boundaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29996079/match-a-whole-word-in-a-string-using-dynamic-regex) and will have to escape the contents, e.g. `{re.escape(keyword_var)}`