# Regex that recognizes ^^ and ^ as different

Tags: python, regex

I am using the Python `re` module.

I can use the regex `r'\bA\b'` (a raw string) to differentiate between `'A'` and `'AA'`: it will find a match in the string `'A'` and no matches in the string `'AA'`.

I would like to achieve the same thing with a carat `^` instead of the `A`: I want a regex which differentiates between `'^'` and `'^^'`.

The problem I have is that the regex `r'\b\^\b'` does not find a match in `'^`'.

Any ideas?

Comment: You could probably use a [lookahead assertion](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html#lookahead-assertions). But as far as I'm aware, these are generally costly computationally, and there may be simpler ways to achieve your required results.

Comment: After a bit more searching I believe that this is more about the `\b` than about the `^`: answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/3241901/1243435 gives a good explanation of the *word boundary* symbol `\b`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use lookaround for this:

```
(?<!\^)\^(?!\^)
```

`\b` is a word boundary, a place between a word character and a non-word character, so your pattern is quite non-specific (doesn't say anything about `A` specifically, `A_` would also not match given that `_` is a word character.

Here, we assert that there needs to be a place where the preceding character is not a caret, then a caret, then a place where the following character is not a caret (which boils down to "the caret must not be in caret company").