# Regex.Replace unexpected behavior

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Here is the code:

```
    var x = "Word1 Word2 @aaa|sss Word3 Word4 @aaa|sss Word5";
    var s = Regex.Replace(x, "\\b@aaa|sss\\b", "55", RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

Expected output:

> Word1 Word2 55 Word3 Word4 55 Word5

Actual:

> Word1 Word2 @aaa|55 Word3 Word4 @aaa|55 Word5

I am sure, this is something silly... why?

This question is not about "special characters" [as in here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3241692/regular-expression-word-boundary-and-special-characters). This is rather not understanding where the problem is. And the question above doesn't have specific case as in here.

Comment: `\b` matches a word boundary, but `@` is not a word character, so the position between the space and the `@` is not a word boundary. Also, you should escape `|` if you want to match a literal pipe rather than alternate

Comment: @CertainPerformance Good catch. I need somehow include this `@` into this search. So... looks like this should do it then: `@"@aaa\|sss\b"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your pattern doesn't work because of two reasons:

- `\b@` won't match a space-at boundary. The space character and the `@` character are both non-word characters. There is no word boundary between them, so you can't use word boundary to match that. One alternative is `(?<=\s)`. Another option is `(?:(?<=\s)|\b)` if you still want to match word boundaries, as well as space-at boundaries.
- `|` is not escaped. This means that your regex means "@aaa" *or* "sss".

Taking these into consideration, you can fix your regex like this:

```
(?<=\s)@aaa\|sss\b
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fsLkf9/2)

Or:

```
(?:(?<=\s)|\b)@aaa\|sss\b
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fsLkf9/1)

Comment: Great! But if I don't really care about whats before `@`. I only care that I have `@aaa\|...` and I only care that whatever comes after `|` is a single word. Hence, I should get away with `@"@aaa\|sss\b"`, correct? For example `my text@aaa|xxxxx<htmlTag>. . . . ` should be ok then

Comment: @T.S. Yes that's right.

Comment: Thank you sir! Great to have gurus like yourself

Answer (score 1):

This is actually the correct behavior, as you can test with online regex sites.

This is the Regex string you're searching for: "@aaa\|sss" (you might also need to escape the \).

You need to escape the | symbol as it usually acts as a "or" sign.
Also remove the word boundaries, as | cannot be part of a word.

Answer (score 0):

Though the above answers work .simple solution for newbies  is to esacpe "OR"(|) with \ and use "/gi" to replace All.Here is demo https://regex101.com/r/jdIfsb/1

```
 var str = "Word1 Word2 @aaa|sss Word3 Word4 @aaa|sss Word5";
     str = str .replace( /@aaa\|sss/gi, "55" )
```

Comment: I will look at this technique later today. Interesting. Meanwhile, please, vote for reopen this question. Thank you