# Regular Expression that matches attribute units in attribute names including special characters

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I am fairly new to using regular expressions and I am stuck on a problem that I am trying to solve. I have issues understanding what's going on and I hope that someone can hint me in the right direction.

**What I am trying to achieve:**

To avoid duplicates in the view, I want to check if an attribute name contains the respective attribute unit. For example if `$attribute['name'] = "Cutting speed (in m/Min.)"` and `attribute['unit'] = "m/min"` the attribute unit should not be displayed as it is already mentioned in the name.

**How I am trying to achieve this:**

I am checking for the attribute unit by using the following regular expression: `~\b' . attribute['unit'] . '\b~i'`
This works well in for the above mentioned example, but not so well if the unit is a special character, like `%` or `"`, for instance.

**The Problems**

While testing for the special character issue I came accross the following phenomenon:

if I use this regex `/\b%\b/` it behaves not as expected and matches the `%` in `bla%bla` but not the `%` if it is preceded or followed by a space: https://regex101.com/r/56iYEI/3

It seems like the % turns the behavior of the regex to its opposite. I tested with other "special characters" as well (" and &), and they seem to have the same effect.

I was directed to this question ([Regular Expression Word Boundary and Special Characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3241692/regular-expression-word-boundary-and-special-characters)) before and read the answers. I now understand that `\b` checks for word boundaries. But it is still unclear to me why it behaves the way it does as soon as a `%` or `"` turns up.

**The questions**

1. How come a `%` turns this checking for word boundaries by `\b` around?
2. How can I achieve my goal to match for alphanumeric units as well as for special character units, like `%` or `"`?

Looking forward to any hints. Thanks in advance!

Comment: A word boundary is a place where a word character is next to a non-word character. Since space and `%` are both non-word characters, there's no word boundary between them.

Comment: for find the alone % Use ```\B%\B```

Comment: @hoseininjast But that won't work for the earlier case. He's looking for a general solution for any type of unit.

Comment: @Barmar jeeez, I can't believe I didn't see this before... "Since space and % are both non-word characters, there's no word boundary between them." This little sentence just clicked so much xD thanks!!!

Comment: I'm not sure this can be solved easily with a regexp. It's closing in on natural language processing.

Comment: @hoseininjast thanks for your suggestion, I had this option in mind as well, but how would I express this in a pattern? Something like `if special character (% or " or &), do \B%\B else do \bunit\b`

Comment: @Barmar ah okay, I see...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A word break is a point between a string of word characters and a string of non-word characters (or start or end). The non-word characters don't have to be a space.

```
 foo"@#bar {}qux
```

In this string the words breaks are before and after `foo`, `bar`, and `qux`.

The expression [`/\b"@#\b/`](https://regex101.com/r/Dz5AMK/1) will match chars between `foo` and `bar`. However [`/\b"@\b/`](https://regex101.com/r/Dz5AMK/2) will not because there is no word (and thus no word break) after the `@`.

---

To solve this, check either a word break or a non-word character. The following expression matches both cases; [`/(^|\W|\b)"@($|\W|\b)/`](https://regex101.com/r/Dz5AMK/4).

```
'~(^|\W|\b)' . attribute['unit'] . '($|\W|\b)~i'
```

---

P.S. If `attribute['unit']` can contain any characters, be sure to quote before using it in the regex using [`preg_quote()`](https://php.net/preg_quote).

Comment: Thanks so much for the detailed explanation as well as the solution. It did the trick in my case!