# regular expression to match exact word with boundries

Tags: regex, go

I am using golang regex to match an exact word with boundaries, for example "apple", "co.", I cannot simply use \b, because the word can have non alphanumeric char in the end, like the example "co."

I try something like:

```
test := `(?i)\b(co.)(?:\s|$)`
re = regexp.MustCompile(test)
matches = re.FindAllString("co. is a secret shortcut ", -1)
```

but this will give me "co. ", I would like to directly get "co.", how can I adjust my regex to achieve it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: have you considered having a nested capture so you can grab only that part later?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regular Expression Word Boundary and Special Characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3241692/regular-expression-word-boundary-and-special-characters)

Comment: @marco.m - Can you explain what you're talking about ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`FindAllStringSubmatch`](https://pkg.go.dev/regexp#Regexp.FindAllStringSubmatch) to give you access to the capture group:

```golang
package main
import ( "fmt"
        "regexp"
        )

func main(){
    // your code goes here
    test := `(?i)\b(co.)(?:\s|$)`
    re := regexp.MustCompile(test)
    matches := re.FindAllStringSubmatch("co. is a secret shortcut ", -1)
    for _, match := range matches {
        fmt.Printf("'%s'", match[1])
    }
}
```

Output:

```
'co.'
```

[Demo on ideone](https://ideone.com/bM93o8)